# Retrieve child elements which are not within other child elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need a way to retrieve elements of a given element which are not children of certain other elements. To distinguish between these "parent" elements I've been using a data attribute.

This is an example of my following HTML stucture:

```
<form method="post" data-component-id="3">
<table border="0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Date of Birth (dd/mm/yyyy)</th>
            <th>Sex</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr data-component-id="8">
            <td>Spouse</td>
            <td><input name="txtFirstName_1" type="text" maxlength="255" id="txtFirstName_1" data-mapping-id="Person.Firstname"></td>
            <td><input name="txtLastName_1" type="text" maxlength="255" id="txtLastName_1" data-mapping-id="Person.Lastname"></td>
            <td><input name="txtDOB_1" type="text" maxlength="10" id="txtDOB_1" data-mapping-id="Person.Birthday"></td>
            <td>
                <select name="ddlSex_1" id="ddlSex_1" data-mapping-id="Person.Sex">
                    <option value=""></option>
                    <option value="Male">Male</option>
                    <option value="Female">Female</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr data-component-id="9">
            <td>Child</td>
            <td><input name="txtFirstName_2" type="text" maxlength="255" id="txtFirstName_2" data-mapping-id="Person.Firstname"></td>
            <td><input name="txtLastName_2" type="text" maxlength="255" id="txtLastName_2" data-mapping-id="Person.Lastname"></td>
            <td><input name="txtDOB_2" type="text" maxlength="10" id="txtDOB_2" data-mapping-id="Person.Birthday"></td>
            <td>
                <select name="ddlSex_2" id="ddlSex_2" data-mapping-id="Person.Sex">
                    <option value=""></option>
                    <option value="Male">Male</option>
                    <option value="Female">Female</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr data-component-id="9">
            <td>Child</td>
            <td><input name="txtFirstName_3" type="text" maxlength="255" id="txtFirstName_3" data-mapping-id="Person.Firstname"></td>
            <td><input name="txtLastName_3" type="text" maxlength="255" id="txtLastName_3" data-mapping-id="Person.Lastname"></td>
            <td><input name="txtDOB_3" type="text" maxlength="10" id="txtDOB_3" data-mapping-id="Person.Birthday"></td>
            <td>
                <select name="ddlSex_3" id="ddlSex_3" data-mapping-id="Person.Sex">
                    <option value=""></option>
                    <option value="Male">Male</option>
                    <option value="Female">Female</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<input type="button" name="submit" value="SUBMIT">
```

***Note***: The reason there are two `data-component-id="9"` attributes is because I treat this attribute as a type for mapping purposes in my back-end. (8 = Spouse data, 9 = Child data)

I created a JavaScript function which accepts one element and recursively builds a `Component` object, holding an ID, an array of its fields, and sub-components (recursive).

```
// Component Object
function Component(componentID, fields, subComponents) {
    this.ComponentID = componentID; // Numeric
    this.Fields = fields; // Array
    this.Components = subComponents; // Array
}

// Recursively build component (and sub-components)
$.fn.formDataToComponent = function() {
    var componentID = $(this).attr("data-component-id");
    var componentName = "";
    var fields=[];
    var subComponents=[];
    var subComponentsIndex=0;

    // Recursively create the sub components
    $(this).find("[data-component-id]").each(function(oSubComponent){
        subComponents[subComponentsIndex] = $(oSubComponent).formDataToComponent();
        subComponentsIndex++;
    });

    $(this).find('[data-mapping-id]').each(function() {
        // $(this).find('[data-mapping-id]') will retrieve all elements with the data attribute (therefore 12 elements will be selected)
        // With the list of these elements, I want to select ONLY those which are closest to the parent element with the attribute "data-component-id". 
        // Therefore in this particular scenario I only want to select the 4 elements of each "tr" element with each recursive call. 
        // I need to do so in a way that is dynamic and is based on the data attribute as I'll be using this with various forms. 
    });

    return new Component(componentID, componentName, fields, subComponents);
}
```

I've looked at using the `.not()` function in jQuery but I don't think this works how I think it does. I'll continue searching for the solution, but if anyone knows of an easy/efficient way to do so please, I would really appreciate the help!

**Solution**

> For a solution to your problem, check jQuery's .filter function here: http://api.jquery.com/filter/

```
// Get list of sub components
var subComponentArray = $(this).find("[data-component-id]");

// Get all fields that are not within the sub components
$(this).find('[data-mapping-id]').filter(function(){ 
    return $(this).closest(subComponentArray).length === 0;}).each(function(index) {
        // DO STUFF
    });
```

Comment: you can use .children() instead of .find(). I think that filters only the top-level elements based on a specific selector.

http://api.jquery.com/children/

Comment: That won't work, they technically are contained within various div elements, etc. I absolutely must ensure that each element is not contained in a list of other elements.

Comment: Then maybe check the .filter function here:

http://api.jquery.com/filter/

and do something like

$(this).find('[data-mapping-id]').filter(function(){ return $(this).closest("[parent selector you don't want]").length === 0; }).each(function() { .... })

Comment: @klikas It looks like a relevant answer

Comment: You can pass function to `.not()` which can be used as filtering condition. But it would be easier to help if only you provided minimalistic sample replicating your issue with relevant HTML markup and concrete example of what you are looking for

Comment: @A.Wolff Agreed, I've updated the question and included the HTML rather than just the structure. I'm currently testing the `filter()` function and will try incorporating the `not()` function in a bit

Comment: I'm still not sure what you want to select or exclude nor what is `this` in your example. Can you post a concrete example regarding your HTML markup about what you want to select or not?  `// This selects all 6 fields, however I only want the immediate fields of the given element.` What do you mean?

Comment: @A.Wolff Sorry I went to fast and forgot to add the attributes. I've updated the HTML and added more of a description for what I'm trying to select.

Comment: I'm sorry but it is still unclear what you are talking about. I still have no idea which 4th elements you want to select. You said: `I want to select ONLY those which are closest to the parent element with the attribute "data-component-id"`  Closest? As i understand it, the `parent element with the attribute "data-component-id"` is the form with `data-component-id="3"`?! If so, what means then the `closest` 4th ones??? Is that all in first `tr`? Or all child of first `td` of each `tr`? Or what???  Why don't you just explecitely tell WHICH elements you want to select??? IDs?

Comment: `$("form").formDataToComponent()` is called initially.
This function is called recursively from within on each element which has the `data-component-id` attribute (so it will be called 3 more times since there are 3 `tr` elements)
For each recursion, retrieve all of the elements (input & select) with the `data-mapping-id` attribute (so each `tr` element has 4 elements with the mapping attribute) This javascript function will be used on other forms in my system, so it MUST be dynamic and using IDs isn't the solution I want as I won't always know what the IDs are.

Comment: @klikas You're solution with the `filter()` function worked! Could you please post as an answer and I'll mark it for you

Comment: @MPaul glad I could help! I have posted it as an answer. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a solution to your problem, check jQuery's .filter function here:

http://api.jquery.com/filter/

and do something like this:

```
$(this).find('[data-mapping-id]').filter(function(){ 
    return $(this).closest("[parent selector you don't want]").length === 0;
 }).each(function() { .... });
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be able to use `not()`. Using your Root, Child and Field tags as example if you only wanted the nested `Field` inside `Child` you can do:

```
$('Field').not("Root > Field');
```

This would exclude any `Field` that was a direct child of `Root`

It isn't clear what you are trying to filter exactly